# "Source code does not match the byte code" error while using debugger in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, debugging

I've been doing a Kotlin project in Android Studio lately and since some point debugging has been behaving strangely.
If i set breakpoints, it opens the needed decompiled classes from the android sdk folder (such as Activity.class, Looper.class, Handler.class and Instrumentation.class) and goes through them, but with every step Android Studio shows a red sign with "source code does not match the byte code".
It also looks like the debugger is jumping to wrong lines.
After i made the debugger step through all of them, the app continues to run as if there weren't any problems.
I'm not sure if I oberserved that correctly but this seems to only happen when the breakpoint is in a function in the MainActivity class or if it's in a function of a another class that somehow calls or happens in the context of a function in MainActivity. Then it can be seen how the debugger jumps to the last curly bracket of the function in MainActivity and then opens the first external class, throwing the mentioned error and so on.

Debugging without breakpoints and running the app directly works perfectly fine.

I've already been researching this but it seems to be of quite a unique nature with nearly no or not helping answers.
I already set up the entire project newly and just copied the code from the old class files, and didn't mess around with anything else, but this didn't help.
Invalidating cache and using the "Clean project" and "Rebuild project" tools also do not help.
If you need any more info please let me know.
Thanks in advance for your help!

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9VpG.png)
[often at the beginning of the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vb1h.png)
[after stepping through all of these the app continues to run as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9531E.png)

Answer (score 1):

The current Android Studio is based on IntelliJ idea.

Try this: **File > Invalidate Caches** > Select Clear file System caches

Click on **Invalidate and Restart.**

This should do the trick.

Comment: Sadly this does not help.